# Reason behind the feud between WWE's "Wyatt" family members

Tags: wwe

I saw that Rowen added himself in Team Cena, and his brother Luke Harper is in an opposite team.

That's surprising, because both are monsters. How can one participating in noble cause with Team Cena, against his brother?

Does he want to help Cena or want to take hands on his brother (due to something that I don't know and asked here).

How did this happen and in which episode?

Comment: Relevant meta discussion: [Is a question on WWE on topic?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1449/49)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last televised match of the trio - September 19 Smackdown
Beginning of "breakup" videos - September 29

Wyatt return - Hell in a Cell, October 26
Rowan return - October 31 Smackdown
harper return - November 10 RAW
Episode of faction joining - November 17 RAW.
Reason? Too early to say. Rumours are Vince didn't like them as a group.

**Long Answer:**

*That's surprising, because both are monsters, how can one participating in noble cause with team cena, against his brother.*

Welcome to professional wrestling. Wrestlers change factions all the time. Take someone like **Kane**, who has gone back and forth between *good* and *bad* multiple times in his career. He's just one example, but there's a very large number you can find by a few simple google searches.

*Does he want to help cena or want to take hands on his brother (due to something that I don't know and asked here)
how did this happen and in which episode?*

It's not clear exactly which episode you want information in. I'm *assuming* you're asking in which episode did the *final turn* occur in, in which case the answer is the **[November 17 episode of RAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wyatt_Family#Separation)**. In it, Luke Harper won the Intercontinental Championship, whilst Rowan was revealed as a member of Cena's team, creating a *feud* between them. A list of all their turns can be seen [on their Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wyatt_Family#Separation).

As for what their motives are... who knows? It doesn't seem to have been decided yet. Rumours are always rife in the WWE and they often leak "fake" rumours which can be used to help develop feuds. [Daily Wrestling News](http://dailywrestlingnews.com/vinces-plans-wyatt-family-split-harpers-future-hhhs-thoughts/) reported back on the 7th October, 2014 that Vince McMahon was apparently not their biggest fan:

> One source pointed to the fact the writing was on the wall for the
>   faction and that Vince was essentially killing them off so why not let
>   him have his way and push Harper. This same source expressed concern
>   because Harper is nowhere close to Wyatt on the mic.
>
> Another issue is that with the talent roster so thin and Seth Rollins
>   and Dean Ambrose working towards the top of the card, Vince feels that
>   by splitting The Wyatts, they can end up with two top acts instead of
>   one.

Sean Meyers, a writer for RantSports, speculated:

> Just like all three members of The Shield excelled after their split,
>   the Wyatt Family can achieve the same success. Bray Wyatt is destined
>   to be in the main-event picture for years to come, but the outlook for
>   Harper and Rowan could largely be dictated by their roles at Survivor
>   Series.

This obviously suggests that *in his view* their roles and reasons for their feud will largely be dictated by how well received they are in their Survivor Series fight.

Ultimately, this isn't unusual. Wrestling is fairly dynamic and ratings dictate storylines. If the fans enjoy the role of both brothers on opposite sides, they'll continue with it. If not, it'll disappear before you know it.

Comment: **UGH!** Upvoting this answer seems like it will only encourage questions like this one... [My brain hurts!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrCPIrs90eg)

Comment: @MeatTrademark: I hate the question too. Share your thoughts on the Meta!!

Comment: Say whatever you guys have to say, but I have got my answer.

Comment: @paul: I'm glad I could help. We've no issues with yourself or the WWE. It's really just about the scope of what's on topic on *this site* and what should be asked *in other Stack sites*, or *elsewhere on the web*.